# Assign variables to df with condition and range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
task_name task_id project_id user
zoo      10       100      Nan
zoo      11       110      Nan
foo      22       100      Nan
foo      23       110      Nan
xyz      33       100      Nan
xyz      34       110      Nan
qwe      40       100      Nan
```

Where `task_name` common, `task_id` is unique and `proejct_id` two variables. So same `task_name` in two dif `project_id` and  unique `task_id`.
I need to assign to column `user` at users but with several condition:
First: all users have coefficient(factor) how many tasks can be assign to this user, for example only 4 from this df. Second: for each user can be assign only one `task_name`, for example user 'dude' can be assign to `task_name` zoo with `task_id` 10 in `project_id` 100 but not in both `task_name` zoo with `task_id` 10 **and** 11 in `project_id` 100 **and** 110. So I need check no double assign in same task_name.
My expect output:

```
task_name task_id project_id user
    zoo      10       100      dude
    zoo      11       110      user2
    foo      22       100      dude
    foo      23       110      user2
    xyz      33       100      dude
    xyz      34       110      user2
    qwe      40       100      dude
```

I trying this but without success:

```
df.apply(lambda x: 'dude' if x['project_id'] == 100 else np.nan, axis=1)
df.sort_values(by='project_id', inplace=True)
df['user'][0:4] = 'dude'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sample data seems solution should be simplify - if project_id is `100` assign `dude` else `user2`:

```
df['user'] = np.where(df['project_id'] == 100,'dude','user2')
```

If need assign first `N` values in sorted values:

```
df.sort_values(by='project_id', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
df['user'] = np.where(df.index < 4, 'dude','user2')
print (df)
  task_name  task_id  project_id   user
0       zoo       10         100   dude
1       foo       22         100   dude
2       xyz       33         100   dude
3       qwe       40         100   dude
4       zoo       11         110  user2
5       foo       23         110  user2
6       xyz       34         110  user2
```